# Best style for message passing between threads?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to asynchroniously call functions in various threads, each of which has a specific `state`, so I send messages to a given thread and let that thread act on those messages. What I wonder is what is the most reasonable style for those messages. I can think of three possibilities. (All the examples exclude thread mechanics, so as not to complicate them.)

1. Keyword-based messages, with dispatch on state and keyword.

```lisp
(defclass state () ())

(defgeneric dispatch (object method args))

(defmethod dispatch ((object state) (method (eql :bazinga)) args)
  (destructuring-bind (arg1 arg2) args
    (format t "arg1 = ~a, arg2 = ~a~%" arg1 arg2)))

(let ((state (make-instance 'state))
      (msg '(:bazinga 10 20))) ; message example
  (dispatch state (car msg) (cdr msg)))
```

2. Function-based messages, with dispatch on state.

```lisp
(defclass state () ())

(defgeneric bazinga (object arg1 arg2))

(defmethod bazinga ((object state) arg1 arg2)
  (format t "arg1 = ~a, arg2 = ~a~%" arg1 arg2))

(let ((state (make-instance 'state))
      (msg (list #'bazinga 10 20))) ; message example
  (apply (car msg) state (cdr msg)))
```

2.1 Function-based messages, with dispatch on state and with arguments passed via closure (from a comment from RowPJ)

```lisp
(defclass state () ())

(defgeneric bazinga (object arg1 arg2))

(defmethod bazinga ((object state) arg1 arg2)
  (format t "arg1 = ~a, arg2 = ~a~%" arg1 arg2))

(let ((state (make-instance 'state))
      (msg (lambda (obj) (bazinga obj 10 20))))
  (funcall msg state))
```

3. Function-based messages, with "hardcoded dispatch".

```lisp
(defclass state () ()) ; could be a structure instead

(defun state-bazinga (object arg1 arg2)
  (format t "arg1 = ~a, arg2 = ~a~%" arg1 arg2))

(let ((state (make-instance 'state))
      (msg (list #'state-bazinga 10 20))) ; message example
  (apply (car msg) state (cdr msg)))
```

3.1 - analogously with 2.1, skipping here.

I'm unlikely to have any sort of object hierarchy, so it feels to me there is no real difference between these styles. Is it indeed just a matter of personal preference then, or are there objective pros and cons? Will any of these styles likely be easier to use or, instead, more limiting down the road as the program growth? I know it's not a clear cut question, but hopefully it's still reasonably clear what I'm asking.

Comment: What is the difference between 'threaded' and 'non threaded'?

Comment: Could you not make your message objects anonymous functions that take no arguments? That seems like the most natural way to pass around code as an object to me.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig, in the actual threaded implementation I send the messages via a `mailbox`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @RowPJ, I can do that as well. I've added option 2.1, I guess that's what you meant.

Comment: If you have CLOS dispatch and CLOS generic functions, why invent your own dispatch? Why do dispatch at all, when you don't use it in your code. Why use 'message passing', when the default Lisp is oriented towards function calls and functions are first-class values? Questions like these you have to answer yourself. I'd would keep the code as simple and direct as possible.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, thanks for the questions. I have tried to make simple examples to phrase my question but I guess I have lost the necessary context along the way.  I am using and not reinventing CLOS, maybe `dispatch` is an unfortunate name and `process-message` could be better. I need message passing, because I have multiple threads and need to make asynchronous calls from one thread to another, so I use messages and `sb-concurrency:mailbox` for that. What's the alternative to message passing then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> call functions in various threads

A basic model would be a waiting loop which watches its own queue / mailbox and executes the functions put into that queue / mailbox.

Put whatever function you want into that queue.

This can be extended to enqueue both the function and its args.

The LispWorks GUI library uses that model: [apply-in-pane-process](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CAPI-M/html/capi-m-180.htm#pgfId-2230922).

The mental model is simply that `APPLY` is executing in a specific process: `apply-in-process <process> <function> <args>`. In Lisp I would first think functional. APPLY is a basic function calling operator. Now use a similar version, which just does APPLY in a specific process. One can then apply a lambda, a closure, a named function, a CLOS function, ...

With that one can implement all kinds of calling convention one wants.